# How to prevent openapi-generator from using wildcard imports in java

Tags: java, rest, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

How can I prevent `openapi-generator` from using wildcard imports like `import javax.validation.constraints.*;` in Java?

This import is used in every class of a specified REST API in which the keyword `required` is used for a property. For example in this snipped:

```
...
components:
  schemas:
    SimpleRequest:
      description: Simple request with a required property.
      type: object
      required:
        - requestID
      properties:
        requestID:
          type: string
...
```

Here the generated java code has a class for the object SimpleRequest which has the property requestID which can't be Null.
This is indicated by a `@NotNull` above the field in the generated code. Instead of using the wildcard import, the generator could have used this import intead: `import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;`

Comment: Why do you care what import strategy your _generated_ code uses??

Answer (score 0):

By default, the code is generated based on the default templates defined for each languages. For java, you can find the template file used to generate the model DTO [here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/Java/model.mustache).

Since wild card import is mentioned in [1], the code is generated accordingly. You can customize the template files and configure it with the parameter - `templateDirectory`, when generating the code.

[1] https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/Java/model.mustache#L36